# Radio buttons enable multiple checkboxes

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, radio-button

I have the below code.

Phase 1 radio button must enable the 2 checkboxes below it and same thing for phase 2 radio button.

The checkboxes must be disabled again if the other radio button is selected.

I already have 50% of the idea working, but no idea how to do this for phase 2 also.

Below is my code. My JavaScript knowledge is very very poor. Thank you in advance!!

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
</body>
<table border=1>
<tr>
    <td>
        <form name="phaseform" action=""><font size=2>
        <input type="radio" name="phase" value="1" id="phase" onclick="checkbox(0)" />
            <label for="phase1">Phase 1</label>
    </td>
    <td><font size=2>
        <input type="radio" name="phase" value="2" id="phase" onclick="checkbox(1)" />
            <label for="phase2">Phase 2 (after 17 days)</label>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><font size=2>
        <input type="checkbox" disabled checked id="TerminateP1" name="TerminateP1" value="IN">Terminate AD account<br>
        <input type="checkbox" disabled checked id="MailboxAccessP1" name="MailboxAccessP1" value="IN">Grant mailbox access to manager<br>
    </td>
    <td><font size=2>
        <input type="checkbox" disabled checked id="TerminateP2" name="TerminateP2" value="IN">Fully terminate AD account<br>
        <input type="checkbox" disabled checked id="DisableMailboxP2" name="DisableMailboxP2" value="IN">Disable mailbox<br>
    </td>
</tr>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
        function checkbox(val)
        {
            if(val)
        document.phaseform.TerminateP1.setAttribute("disabled",val) 
        else
        document.phaseform.TerminateP1.removeAttribute("disabled",val)
            if(val)
        document.phaseform.MailboxAccessP1.setAttribute("disabled",val)
        else
        document.phaseform.MailboxAccessP1.removeAttribute("disabled",val)
        }
</script>

</table>
</body>
<html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function checkbox(val)
    {
        document.phaseform.TerminateP1.setAttribute("disabled",val) 
        document.phaseform.MailboxAccessP1.setAttribute("disabled",val)
        document.phaseform.TerminateP2.setAttribute("disabled",val) 
        document.phaseform.DisableMailboxP2.setAttribute("disabled",val)
        if(val)
        {
            document.phaseform.TerminateP2.removeAttribute("disabled",val) 
            document.phaseform.DisableMailboxP2.removeAttribute("disabled",val)
        }
        else
        {
            document.phaseform.TerminateP1.removeAttribute("disabled",val)
            document.phaseform.MailboxAccessP1.removeAttribute("disabled",val)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you Tyler, works fine in browser. However, as a HTA application it fails to disable phase 2 checkboxes once activated. Any idea why?

Comment: Added "1" instead of "val" in the first 4 function lines and seems to be working fine now in HTA. Can you please check to see if this could affect anything in a bad way? e.g. TerminateP1.setAttribute("disabled",1)

Answer (score 0):

Removed form, striped Tyler's code and it is now working properly in HTA. Can someone please tell me if the below code could cause any future issues?

```
function checkbox(val)
{
    TerminateP1.setAttribute("disabled",1) 
    MailboxAccessP1.setAttribute("disabled",1)
    TerminateP2.setAttribute("disabled",1) 
    DisableMailboxP2.setAttribute("disabled",1)
    if(val)
    {
        TerminateP2.removeAttribute("disabled") 
        DisableMailboxP2.removeAttribute("disabled")
    }
    else
    {
        TerminateP1.removeAttribute("disabled")
        MailboxAccessP1.removeAttribute("disabled")
    }
}
```